# Allow whitespace in username in url routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a Rails app, I have this current Regex validator below in routes.rb

```
match 'profile/:username' => 'users#show', :as => :profile, :constraints => { :username => /[ a-zA-Z0-9\-\_ ]+/ }
```

This constraints work in rails2 but in rails3 it not work and give me a routing error

No route matches [GET]

the above regexp work for non whitepace username(jai) and for whitespace username(jai lalawat) it not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers replace whitespace with `%20`. So change your regex to match that too.

```
match 'profile/:username' => 'users#show', :as => :profile, :constraints => { :username => /[ a-zA-Z0-9\-\_20% ]+/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add %20 character in your routes.rb for above routes

```
match 'profile/:username' => 'users#show', as: :profile, constraints: { username: /[ a-zA-Z0-9\-\_20% ]+/ }
```